# viewController.delegate is not a member of customer ViewController classes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Sorry if this is an extremely dumb question - but I'm following this tutorial to get a blurred background modal

https://medium.com/@mohau/blurred-background-semi-transparent-modal-view-swift-3-xcode-tutorial-1f67566bb449

And I've done everything the same, but I get errors on the code of the `MainViewControllers` and `ModalViewControllers`, both to do with the 'delegate' identifier.

It's been a while since I last used xcode and swift, so I don't know what is causing the error.

- Why are my delegates not correct?
- Has delegate syntax changed with any recent swift updates?

Here are the code snippets that are causing the errors.
In MainViewController:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        if identifier == "ShowModalView" {
            if let viewController = segue.destination as? ModalViewController {
                viewController.delegate = self //!! value of type 'ModalViewController' has no member 'delegate'
                viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in ModalViewController (on the button action to close the modal view)

```
    @IBAction func cancelButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    delegate?.removeBlurredBackgroundView() //use of unresolved identifier 'delegate'
}
```

The strangest thing is if I download the example from the tutorial it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: where do you define the `delegate` property?

Comment: did your `ModalViewController` class have a property called delegate?

Comment: I forgot to create the delegate variable... I feel dumb, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the rest of the tutorial. I don't know why the author decides to do it that way, but he starts using the delegate and only later on describes how to implement the delegate. Step 15 of [the tutorial](https://medium.com/@mohau/blurred-background-semi-transparent-modal-view-swift-3-xcode-tutorial-1f67566bb449) resolves this.

Comment: Ah, I see it now, I forgot a line. I'm a little embarrassed, thank you very much!